# Terraform AWS provider cannot find aws_codepipeline_webhook resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform 0.11.10 (latest as of this date). I'm trying to use the codepipeline webhooks feature, as described here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline_webhook.html

I have defined a webhook resource as follows:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "foo" { ... }
```

However Terraform complains:

```
Error: aws_codepipeline_webhook.foo: Provider doesn't support resource:
aws_codepipeline_webhook
```

I have re-initialized Terraform.

The documentation definitely exists, and I saw feature request discussing it that was marked as resolved here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4478

Anyone know of a way to get support for it?

Comment: Which AWS provider version are you running? Since 0.10 Terraform has unbundled the versions of providers and core Terraform.

Comment: I was using 1.39 and that webhook was introduced in 1.41! Make that comment an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Terraform 0.10 the providers that interact with external APIs such as AWS have been unbundled and release features with a different cadence to core or each of the other providers.

Thus if you are looking to bring in fixes for provider specific bugs or new features such as new resources/data sources or new functionality in existing resources and data sources then you should also be upgrading your provider versions.

In this case the [`aws_codepipeline_webhook` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline_webhook.html) was released in the [1.41 AWS provider release](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1410-october-18-2018) so your AWS provider version wants to be at least at that version.